# Notification after timer is finished if the device is locked - React Native EXPO?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I have a timer written on React Native (EXPO) similar to the native Android timer.
I use something like that:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    Vibration.vibrate(PATTERN, true); // this works only when app is active
}, 60 * 1000); // time in range 1 - 120 min.
```

How to fire audio signal or/and vibration when the timer is finished and the device is locked and the screen turned off on iOS and Android?
Should I use some of the React Native components or a separate package?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you could run `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to run a simple task every few seconds. The sad news is that `setTimeout` does not work in React Native’s background or suspended mode. This is true for both plain react native apps and with **ExpoKit**.

Thankfully, the [React Native Background Timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer?source=post_page---------------------------) package allows you to run `setTimeout` when the app is in the background. On Android, this works for both suspended mode and background mode, whereas for iOS it only works in the background, and not suspended mode. In other words, on iOS it works as long as the app is in the background, and the phone is locked, but not when the screen is turned off.

Comment: Is there a way now to get the same behavior for IOS as for android?